# Is it possible to store a new mysql database on another drive?

Tags: windows, mysql

I am running MySQL on Windows XP.  My data directory is: c:/database/data/

I want to create a new database but store it's data on m:/database/data/

Is it possible to keep the existing data on c:\ and the new data in m:\?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using [NTFS symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link). Create a link in your database directory, pointing to m:\database\data\yourdatabasename.